# How does IE6 render absolute positioning different?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer-6, css-position

Any hacks to make my absolute positioning render how it is suppose to on IE6?

Comment: Two points: Don't ask two different questions in the title and in the text, it just creates confusion about which question you actually want get answered. And please add some details about what goes wrong, what do you expect, and most importantly, code that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: Are you actually talking about hasLayout bug?

Comment: Can't you make your question more specific? IE6 supports absolute positioning, albeit with a number of bugs and caveats and tricks and workarounds. To understand which you ran into and which you need more details are needed.

Comment: @Johnannes...how is it not clear what I'm asking? Seems pretty black and white to me.It's a two part question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.corephp.com/blog/perfect-absolute-positioning-in-ie6/